# Runtime generation of accordions in extjs 4

Tags: dynamic, extjs4

How can I generate accordions dynamically using ExtJS 4?

Comment: Please provide more specific information on what you need. Show any existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I didn't check that but it may be useful to you.

```
 Ext.getCmp('id').insert(position, Accordianclass);
```